# How can you disable inline validation for a z3c.form on Plone?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, plone, z3c.form

I have a wrapped form that is custom. Inline Validation is having a fit because the javascript runs into error because the input data.errmsg is null and it can't handle that.

It spits out this traceback:

```
2014-12-16 16:28:15 WARNING plone.protect error parsing dom, failure to add csrf token to  
response for url http://localhost:8080/Plone/.../@@questionsinglepart/@@z3cform_validate_field
```

For an error in this part of the inline javascript:

```
   if (fname) {
     $form.ajaxSubmit({
        url: append_url_path($form.attr('action'), '@@z3cform_validate_field'),
        data: {fname: fname, fset: fset},
        iframe: false,
        success: function (data) {
          render_error($field, data.errmsg);
         },
          dataType: 'json'
      });
    }
```

How can I disable the inline validation for a form so I don't get the errors when it attempts to validate?

Comment: I removed the inline_validation.js and added custom js but the WARNING still fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more official ways to do this, but I find that injecting a JavaScript one-liner on relevant pages (in your templates) or globally (in portal_javascripts or via viewlet) solved my problems with this:

```
$('.z3cformInlineValidation').removeClass('z3cformInlineValidation');
```